# authserver and worldserver binaries missing after fresh bash dashboard install

Tags: ubuntu, azerothcore

After following the instructions for the [AC bash dashboard instructions](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/ac-dashboard-core-installation) meticulously, it looks like the authserver and worldserver binaries do not get installed in azerothcore-wotlk/env/dist/bin as expected and are missing. When trying to run the authserver, this error comes up:

```
Deno version check:
Version 1.9.1 is already installed
Running authserver ...
/root/azerothcore-wotlk/env/dist/bin/authserver doesn't exists!
```

I used the AC bash dashboard before a couple of months ago and it worked well, not sure if anything has changed since then.

I noticed during compile that I got these 2 errors, not sure if it's related:

```
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1051: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/all] Error 2
Killed
make[2]: *** [src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/build.make:1354: src/server/game/CMakeFiles/game.dir/Globals/ObjectMgr.cpp.o] Error 137
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04.02 container. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the actual error is missing, can you send the full console error inside a pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a change was made to the script but I just tried it again (5th attempt) and it worked.